# Vue.js is not working when its in seperate file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue.js

When i put my script code in seperate file in js then my component is not working, only when i directly write code in view. Any suggestion why is that happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/coligo/txpy7ug4/

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <ul class="list-group">
      <post v-for="comment in comments" :post="comment"></post>
    </ul>

    <div id="comment-box">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a comment..." v-model="comment" @keyup.enter="postComment">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="postComment">Submit</button>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<template id="post-template">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" @click="upvote" :class="{disabled: upvoted}"></i>
    <span class="label label-primary">@{{ votes }}</span>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" @click="downvote" :class="{disabled: downvoted}"></i>
    <a>@{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is in different file than your JS code, You have to require that in your vue instance like explained [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-using-templates-from-external-file?page=1):

**component.js**

```
module.export = {
template: require('./templates/template.html'),
data: function(){
    return {
    text: "Hello World!"
    };
}
};
```

**template.html**

```
<h1>{{ text }}<h1>
```